# cassandra compactions not completing due to low disk space

Tags: cassandra

all three machines have a 1.6T data volume, but the imbalance is not allowing compaction to complete on one node (10.8.5.61):

```
[root@is05 ~]# df -h /export/
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg01-data
                  1.6T  1.6T   28G  99% /export
[root@10.8.5.61 ~]# nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                                       Rack
UN  10.8.5.61   1.56 TB    256     34.8%             d8ac5a47-6cd4-47b6-96c5-1d87ccaca71d  rack1
UN  10.8.7.49   1.18 TB    256     30.1%             5c860455-1b27-4a0b-a5ed-357c2fa3cb75  rack1
UN  10.8.5.179  1.49 TB    256     35.1%             9a080b1a-09df-42b7-b627-d5221408289f  rack1
```

Is there a way I can move the data to the second node to allow more breathing room? what can I do to reclaim space on the node with the most data on it?

Answer (score 2):

The data distribution between nodes depends on your data model, and it looks like it's very skewed (with 256 tokens distribution should be quite good) -  you can check for presence of the big partitions on the 1st & 3rd machines.

IMHO, you have several possibilities (depending on the version of Cassandra, of course):

- Add a new server into cluster, and wait to rebalance. This is good idea anyway, because with default compaction strategy you need to have up to 50% of disk space free to perform compactions;
- add a new disk to machine, and configure 2nd data directory, so Cassandra has a room for tasks;
- Try to cleanup garbage in individual tables (this [blog post](https://academy.datastax.com/support-blog/cleaning-tombstones-datastax-dse-and-apache-cassandra) from DataStax support is good overview of techniques to try);
- try to force compaction of individual SSTables (start with small one) via JMX (`CompactionManager` bean, the `forceUserDefinedCompaction` operation) - see this [great article](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/10/18/user-defined-compaction.html) for example how to run it through jmxterm. You can use some other tool, like JConsole to perform this